# getting 25% width divs to sit side by side and edge to edge of container div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi I'm trying to get these `<divs>`'s to sit inside a containing  (inner) `<div>`, the idea is to have a max of 4 `<divs>`'s in a row with a double border (1px solid) and a margin of 30px between the divs at the same time as having the first and last sitting on the edge of the inner div.

This is the code I've done but I can't seem to get the margin to work the way the design needs it to.

```
<div class="client-list-container clearfix">
    <div class="client-logo-container">
        <div class="logo-container">
            <div class="client-logo">
                <div class="logo">
                    <p>Client Logo</p>
                </div>  <!-- logo div ends -->
            </div> <!-- client logo div ends -->
        </div> <!-- logo container div ends -->
    </div> <!-- client logo container div ends -->
```

I have 6 of these repeated the same way with the first div (client-list-container clearfix) closeing after the 6th.

Here is the CSS I've used and yes I have an empty one but thats cause I was trying to see if another div could help with an idea of doing a margin-left: -30px; on one and a padding-left: 30px; might solve the problem but didn't work out.

```
.client-list-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.client-logo-container {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;    
}

.logo-container {
}

.client-logo{
    border: 1px solid #9bb8be;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

.logo{
    border: 1px solid #9bb8be;
    margin: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px 48px;
}
```

Not posted on here before so not sure if I've posted this the best way possible, Sorry if it's not posted the best way.

Comment: looks like you may be missing a closing `</div>`

Comment: <div class="client-list-container clearfix">   I've closed this div at the end of the 6th repeat its the container for all the divs and then I have the inner container that wraps all the inner content.

Comment: yes I do not see the closing `</div>` for it. Did you forget to include it with your sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close with your negative margin + padding idea, however one thing to keep in mind is that the default `box-sizing` property is `content-box`. This means that the total width of the element is comprised of the width **plus** the padding. So your elements would have actually been 25% + 30px wide, making them wider than 100%. So really what you want is `border-box`, where if you set the width at 25%, this includes the padding in that width.

For example, this should work:

```
.client-list-container {
    margin-left: -30px;
}

.client-logo-container {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Note that I took off the `width: 100%` property from `.client-list-container`.

For reference, you can put code snippets into jsFiddle to make it easier for people to help you out. Here's the working solution in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6vcs51pd/

Comment: Christian Varga Thank you so much I've been bugged by this problem all day and its been driving me mad. Your solution has worked a treat once again thank you.